# Typo3: FE Login with POST Request to external app server

Tags: post, authentication, typo3, frontend, typoscript

I recently started getting into Typo3 but now I have to implement something for work and I have no clue where to start.

The requirements:

- I have to add a separate page that can only be accessed by frontend
  users. (so far no problem)
- These frontend users should be able to login with the same password
  as they got for their iOS app. (uh-oh)
- The separate page should display data from the app. (less of an uh-oh 
  but connected to the previous point)

After talking to the developer of the app, he made a specific POST request that can be used for the webpage. I am also getting a json-file with the required data that I need to display upon successful login.

My question lies with the login. How do I go about implementing this? I use the extension felogin to provide the login form on the page.

The POST request is looking sort of like this:
`https://domain.at/api/queryMediaItems`. It needs user and password, declared as user and pwd. In the body there should be a json object with the language, e.g.:

```json
{"language":"de-at"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a SSO (SingleSignOn) as your users need to identify against the iOS-app.

[This](https://de.slideshare.net/tschikarski/single-sign-on-with-typo3) might give you a concept.

You also can look inside the code of [some extension](https://extensions.typo3.org/?L=0&id=1&tx_solr%5Bq%5D=sso)